# Проблема с JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Есть js код:

```
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    var button = buttons[i];
    if (button.getAttribute('type') == 'submit'
            && button.getAttribute('value') == 'Add') {
        button.addEventListener("click", function() {
            hideDeleteButton();
        });
    }
}

function hideDeleteButton() {
    var commentsList = document.getElementById("comment-list");
    // deleteButton.style.display = 'none';
    alert("Hello!");
}
```

Проблема в том что он выполняется только один раз при нажатии на "Add", 
что бы он выполнился еще раз нужно перезагрузить страницу.
Я не силен в JS, и знаю что во время нажатия на "Add" выполняется не только этот js код. 
Как исправить это ?

Comment: А какой action стоит на кнопке add ???

Comment: Сделайте рабочий пример на jsfiddle, пожалуйста. Из представленного кода можно только сказать, что все работает. :)

Answer (score 1):

А какой action стоит на кнопке add ??? вообще то если в  то ф-ция **hideDeleteButton** будет вызываться каждый раз при нажатии кнопки, если вам нужно по нажатию весь код запускать то надо его весь обернуть в ф-цию и вызывать её при нажатии на кнопку